# Redirect multiple domains to subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have multiple domains pointing to my VPS (Virtual Private Server). What I want is, for example, if I write: `www.domain1.com`, redirect to `www.domain.com:8080/app1`, because I have apps with Tomcat. The same with `www.domain2.com`, to `www.domain2.com:8080/app2`, etc.

Can I do that with htaccess?

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried reading the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/)? Have you tried asking your question on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Redirect+multiple+domains+to+subdirectories)?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know the best approach for reach that. I have found even a web service who do this for you, or doing that with cpanel (I don't have any panel). Maybe my question is not clear. I only want to know the best approach.

Comment: So you want it so when someone types `http://www.domain1.com/` into their address bar, the browser gets redirected to `http://www.domain.com:8080/app1` this changing the URL in their address bar? There's no "best" approach to this, there's only one approach, *redirect the browser* using mod_alias or mod_rewrite.

Comment: @jav_000 You should always include the approach(es) you have tried in your question. This will save you from downvotes due to no research on your part. If you have tried something and it didn't work, you could get a pointer in the right direction; if you just ask "how to do this" it looks like you haven't bothered to try anything and are hoping to get a complete solution without having to do any work yourself.

Comment: @JonLin thanks for the link. mod_rewrite is exactly what I need. I'm trying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}      ^www.domain1\.com$

RewriteRule  ^(.*)             http://www.domain1.com:8080/app1$1      [R=301,L]
```

in .htaccess, and the same with the other.